# testing two classes don't exist with less css

Tags: css, less

I have an element lets say it could have .foo or .bar or both or none as a class:

```
<div class="foo bar">green</div>
<div class="foo">green</div>
<div class="bar">green</div>
<div class="something-else">red</div>
```

How can I test that the element doesn't have either class.

I tried something like this, but it doesn't work as expected:

```
div {
  background: green;
  &:not(.foo) and &:not(.bar) {
    background: red;
  }
}
```

I don't see many examples using less and not(), only 1 in their docs.

Comment: `:not()` is regular CSS, not LESS-specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To say *not* to multiple conditions in a CSS selector, you need to chain them together:  `div:not(.foo):not(.bar)`

```
div {
  background: green;
  &:not(.foo):not(.bar) {
    background: red;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is always the pure css alternative.

```
div { background: red; }
div.foo, div.bar { background: green; }
```

Comment: The code is part of a much larger ruleset and is using &:not(.foo) -- I just need to do the equivalent of not(.foo or .bar)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it by nesting two &:not() rules, but I'm not sure this is the best way.

```
div {
  background: green;
  &:not(.foo) {
    &:not(.bar) {
      background: red;
    }
  }
}
```